# Why does my model's accuracy change depending on whether it is loaded from a pickle or newly trained?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle

I am creating a custom implementation of the Viola-Jones algorithm. When I train the classifier and evaluate its accuracy, it accurately classifies 462 out of 1000 examples accurately. However, when I load the same model from a pickle file and test its accuracy on the same dataset, it's accuracy suddenly becomes 999 out of 1000.

I tried varying the hyperparameters of the algorithm, but the accuracy immediately after training is always 462/1000, which is the number of negative examples in the dataset. I believe that this means `clf.classify(x)` is always returning 0, but I do not understand why that should no longer be the case when I load the model from a pickle file.

```
training = training[0:1000] #An array of tuples, first element in each tuple is a numpy array, the second is its classification

try:
    clf = ViolaJones.load("viola_jones") #Loads classifier from pickle
    print("Loaded classifier from file")
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to load classifier from file: %s" % str(e))
    pos_num, neg_num = 0, 0
    for x, y in training:
        if y == 1:
            pos_num += 1
        else:
            neg_num += 1
    clf = ViolaJones(feature_num=2)
    clf.train(training, pos_num, neg_num)

    clf.save("viola_jones") #Saves classifier to pickle

correct = 0
for x, y in training:
    prediction = clf.classify(x)
    correct += prediction == y
print("Correctly labeled %d out of %d training examples" % (correct, len(training)))
```

I run the file once to train the model, evaluate it, and save it to file (I am using the training set for both training and evaluation for simplicity although I am aware it is bad practice). Upon running the file again, it will instead load the model from the file and evaluate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe one of the two: `1. when you trained/fitted your model, did you set the parameter 'seed' to a fixed value?` - If not, everytime you predict the same dataset a new random seed will be set and the prediction will be completely random. `2. are you sure that the columns from both loaded files are in the same order?` - The order of the columns it's whats important when you train the model, not the column names. So when predicting, the columns needs to be in the same order.

Comment: I don't use any seed parameter in the algorithm. The dataset is loaded from the same file each time I run it, so I never change the order of the training examples or the columns of the training data.

Comment: Have you verified that after training the classifier indeed predicts "0" for each input?

Comment: Also, try running the training and NOT saving it. Maybe the process of pickling it messes things up?

Comment: I checked and the classifier does indeed predict "0" for each input. I tried running the training without saving it and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in the `clf.train` function, I alter the `training` array with my feature engineering since the array is passed in by reference. That is why the model performed poorly on evaluation immediately after training since it was effectively engineering features based on the engineered features. Reloading the training data before evaluation fixed the issue.